# configure: error: Can't find Tk configuration definitions

Tags: 16.04, gtk, gtk3

## Problem

configuring the build of gtkwave from source gives me the following error:

```
checking for Tk configuration... configure: error: Can't find Tk configuration definitions. Use --with-tk to specify a directory containing tkConfig.sh
```

The commmand I use is

```
./configure --prefix=/usr
```

## Question

Where can I locate Tk configuration definitions in Ubuntu 16.04?

## Further details

- gtk 3 has been installed with `sudo apt-get install libgtk-3-dev`
- there is no `tk` in `/usr/include`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The APT will help you as [`gtkwave` is packaged](https://packages.ubuntu.com/source/xenial/gtkwave) (so we have both source-code and binary packages in the repositories):

```
sudo apt-get build-dep gtkwave
```

and then retry. You can read more about `build-dep` sub-command in [`man apt-get`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/apt-get.8.html).

Also consider to use [Checkinstall](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CompilingSoftware#Installing_the_Package) by `sudo checkinstall make install` instead of `sudo make install` on the last stage.